# Crossfire Compatibility MSi R7 370 4GB and 2GB

Tags: graphics-cards

I was wondering if it is possible to use crossfire with the MSi R7 370 4gb and the MSi R7 370 2gb. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crossfire is a little more forgiving than SLI. You **can** crossfire these cards together, but you should be warned that doing so means being hamstrung by the maximum values of the weaker card.

For example, you will have the computational power of two 370s (minus crossfire overhead), but you will be stuck with a maximum of 2GB of VRAM. Depending on what you are pushing through these cards, your performance could very well decrease significantly.